# phpmyadmin Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\setsession1.php on line

Tags: php

Buen dia tengo un problema por que en mi codigo me aparace
Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\setsession1.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\setsession1.php on line 19

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["idusuario"])){
    header("Location: welcome.php");
}

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['usuario']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']);
    $error = '';

    $sha1_pass = sha1($password);

    $sql = "SELECT  usuario, password FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND password = '$sha1_pass'";
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
    $rows = $result->num_rows;

    if($rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION['idusuario'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['deportes'] = $row['usuario'];

        header("location: welcome.php");
        } else {
        $error = "El nombre o contraseña son incorrectos";
    }
}
?>
```

mi base de datos es id, usuario, name,apellido, password, images, fecha

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" > 

    <label for="user" class="label" >Usuario</label>
    <input id="user" type="text" class="input">
    </div>
    <div class="group">
    <label for="pass" class="label">Contraseña</label>
    <input id="pass" type="password" class="input" data-type="password">
    </div>
    <div class="group">
    <input id="check" type="checkbox" class="check" checked>
    <label for="check"><span class="icon"></span> Recordar inicio de sesion</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
    <input type="submit" name="login"  class="button" value="INICIAR">
    </form>
```

Comment: Puedes indicarnos cuáles son las líneas 18 y 19 de tu archivo setsession1.php?

Answer (score 0):

debes verificar que tus variables estén inicializadas  para prevenir errores, puedes inicializarlas con un null o algo que la identifique como vacia.

```
$var = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

El formulario de html debe contener por cada input a enviar el atributo `name` de la siguiente forma

```
<input name="usuario" id="user" type="text" class="input">
<input name="password" id="pass" type="password" class="input" data-type="password">
```